# White UINavigationBar when using documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, download

I would like users to be able to click a button to view a file from the internet. The code looks like this:

```
func downloadFile(button: MyButton) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(button.indexPath!) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    //Get documents directory URL
    let documentsDirectoryUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first

    let sourceUrl = NSURL(string:"https://download.com/file.pdf")!

    //Get the file name and create a destination URL
    let fileName = sourceUrl.lastPathComponent!
    let destinationURL = documentsDirectoryUrl!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

    //Hold this file as an NSData and write it to the new location
    if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfURL: sourceUrl) {
        fileData.writeToURL(destinationURL, atomically: false)   // true

        let viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL:destinationURL)
        viewer.delegate = self
        viewer.presentPreviewAnimated(true)
    }
}

func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
    return self
}
```

In the above version of the code, I get two errors: `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions` and `Cannot find preview item for proxy`, however the preview looks exactly as I'd want it, albeit without any font customisation of the navigationBar title (which would be nice).

Having read some questions on here, I decided to try changing the `return self` code to `return self.navigationController!`. This removed the error messages as hoped, but also meant that the navigation was unreadable.

My UINavigationController is extended in the normal way to set background colours etc:

```
class NavigationController : UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarPosition: UIBarPosition.Any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

If I comment out the setBackgroundImage line, I can see everything as expected, however the barTintColor clearly changes slightly - I don't know if this is as the result of the lack of transparency support or something? This is the best effort so far, but the colour change is annoying me! It also becomes part of the existing navigation stack, rather than showing up as a pop over, as it did when the ViewController was returned rather than the NavigationController.

Is there a way to 1) make this happen as a pop over (perhaps with a customised navigationController), or 2) fix the background colour change. Many thanks in advance!